# AWS securing accessKeyId and secretAccessKey

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to make javascript access Amazon S3 bucket, and everything works as expected. I need to secure the javascript sothat I dont store the accessKeyId and secretAccessKey in code or TFS. Below is the bit which passess the access and secret keys.

```
      AWS.config.update({
        region: '--region-code-here--',
        accessKeyId: '--keyhere--',
        secretAccessKey: '--secretkey-here--'
     });

     const s3 = new AWS.S3();
     //... more code...
```

According to amazon https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-browser.html, the suggested way is to Using Amazon Cognito Identity or Using web federated identity than hardcoded in the script. I find it hard to follow the amazon documentation in my S3 context.

Accessing S3 via javascript is part of a larger application, and I cannot prompt the user for separate credentials for the JS to access the S3 bucket.

Any tips very much appreciated. **The ultimate goal is to secure the access key being hardcoded.**

Comment: Is this code running in a web browser, or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JavaScript code is running in a web page, your app will not be able to access your S3 bucket unless it has credentials or you make the bucket public. Assuming you don't want to make the bucket public, you need to find a way to get credentials to the app.

Typically you would want to authenticate the user before you hand out credentials (because those credentials will be visible in the app) and you can do both with a dedicated server application. Or you can do this more easily with [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) or [WIF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc.html), which will authenticate the client and convert that into a set of credentials for a given IAM role. Or, of course, you could ask the user to supply AWS credentials, but I'm assuming that's not appropriate in this case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. My main app will be authenticated before loading the javascript page which calls S3 bucket. I cannot ask the user to provide the AWS credentials and I cannot hard-code it in javascript (because it will be visible and also checked into TFS, which I don't want to happen). Amazon documentation looks not specific. Do you have any more pointers on how to implement my scenario ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying that your user visits a sign-on page to authenticate to your backend and then is redirected into a second web page that itself accesses S3?

Comment: Then your server can furnish temporary AWS credentials to the web page for use with the AWS SDK, or your server can simply serve pages that include pre-signed S3 URLs so that the client doesn't have to use the AWS SDK to get the objects, or your server can proxy requests to get the objects from S3. If all you're doing is getting objects from S3 then I'd use the pre-signed URL approach. If you need more complex S3 API interaction in the client then vend temporary credentials to the client.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. My JS does CRUD operations on files on the S3 bucket.

Comment: OK, so either the web client interacts with the S3 APIs directly (in which case your server needs to send AWS credentials to the web client) or your web client asks your server to interact with S3 on its behalf (in which case the client doesn't need AWS credentials)\. Also, on the topic of CRUD, you can't update S3 objects (you would delete and replace).